# TGMMap Accessed Denied

Tags: delphi

I am using GMLib v1.5.0 and seem to be having a strange error when using the GMMap component.

I created a small project in Delphi XE7 with the following setup in an attempt to resolve the error:
TForm, TWebBrowser , TButton and TGMMap. The TGMMap is set to use the TWebBrowser as its browser. The application is accessing the web via a proxy server. On the TButton click event I have added the following code:

```
procedure TForm6.Button3Click(Sender: TObject);

begin

GMMap1.Active := True;

GMMap1.RequiredProp.Zoom := 3;

end;
```

On the TGMMap AfterPageLoaded event I have the following code:

```
procedure TForm6.GMMap1AfterPageLoaded(Sender: TObject; First: Boolean);

begin

if First then

GMMap1.DoMap;

end;
```

The app works on all other computers on our network which range from windows xp to windows 8, except one. On this specific machine running windows 8 whenever I click on the button to execute the GMMap1.Active := True; code I get an Access Denied error and no further errors, the Google map is also not displayed in the TWebBrowser component either. I have disabled any antiviruse as well but still no luck. If I execute the following code WebBrowser1.Navigate('http://www.google.com/maps'); using the TWebBrowser the application works fine it only seems to be when using the TGMMap component.

There is a possibility that this one PC may be the issue but need confirmation. Has anyone else had this error? What is GMMap trying to access that is being denied by the system?

Answer (score 0):

Start->Control panels->Network,internet-> Internet options-> click card Security and decrease security level (Internet,middle high).
Good luck..